Maximum fractional matching using minimal number of fractional edges
Ive been trying to find an algorithm that returns the maximum fractional matching in a graph that assigns the least amount of fractional values to edges.
In this paper they show an algorithm for a node cover with the same constraint (but for nodes instead of edges) - does it not also solve the matching problem? I've tried to see if it can be used for it and thought that maybe it's just what I was looking for.
could someone please help me with clarification on this?
